# How to configure path or set environment variables for installation?

Tags: environment-variables, paths

I'm aiming to install APE in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, a simple code for pseudopotential generation. I'm having this error message while running ./configure:

```
checking for gsl-config... no
checking for GSL - version >= 1.0... no
*** The gsl-config script installed by GSL could not be found
*** If GSL was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
*** your path, or set the GSL_CONFIG environment variable to the
*** full path to gsl-config.
configure: error: could not find required gsl library
```

I checked and I have the GSL already installed:

```
:~/Programas/ape-2.2.0$ dpkg -l | grep gsl
ii  libgsl0ldbl                    1.16+dfsg-1ubuntu1 
            i386     GNU Scientific Library (GSL) -- library package
```

So I have the library but the program installation isn't finding it. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Do you have the GSL _development_ package installed (can you add the output of `dpkg -l | grep GSL` to your question please)?

Comment: Ok corrected, it's Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the library package GLS appears as installed on Software Center. There there are another GLS packages but they are not issued as 'libraries'

Comment: Try installing the `libgsl0-dev` package (that's _gee-ess-ell-zero_)

Comment: That worked, GSL found while running ./configure, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GSL include and library environments are provided in this case by the `gsl-config` program (which is a kind of mini `pkg-config` specifically for GSL) e.g.

```
$ gsl-config --cflags --libs
-I/usr/include
-L/usr/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

The `gsl-config` program is provided by package `libgsl0-dev` so the error is telling you that you need to install that package.